# how to create custom database in `MongoDB` and how to connect that database using meteorjs

Tags: meteor

I need how to create ***custom database*** in ***MongoDB*** and how to connect that database using `meteorjs` .

Comment: what do you mean by "custom database"?

Comment: create in MongoDb with our database name @imslavko

Answer (score 4):

You can invoke Meteor with the `MONGO_URL` environment variable set to the desired instance:

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017 meteor
```

If your MongoDB handles multiple databases, you can indicate which one to use by appending it to the URL:

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb meteor

MONGO_URL='mongodb://<user>:<pass>@localhost:27017/mydb' meteor
```

Comment: Thanq... for saying. and How to insert custom login details into (MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb test ) test db.

Comment: How to insert custom login details into (MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb test ) test db.@EpokK

Comment: `MONGO_URL='mongodb://<user>:<pass>@localhost:27017/mydb' meteor`